# searchlogic - array error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

I have the following controller method

```
def app_used_by_Lab
    per_id = params[:id]

    @search1 = Apparatus.used_by_specific_lab(per_id).search(params[:search]) # both 'used_by_specific_lab' & 'lab_created' are named_scopes which return results from the same table
    @search2 = Apparatus.lab_created(per_id).search(params[:search])
    @search = @search2 + @search1
    @search.order ||= :descend_by_RPR_DATE_CREATED
    @apparatuses = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
end
```

If I change the code to  `'@search = @search1'`, it works fine and return me the results but when I do `'@search = @search2 + @search1'`, I get the error message below:

```
TypeError in ApparatusesController#app_used_by_Lab

can't convert Searchlogic::Search into Array
```

Is it not possible to use searchlogic on arrays?

Is there any solution to the above problem?

Thanks a lot for your precious help.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this:

```
@search = @search2.to_s + @search1.to_s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion but it's not working :( am now getting: undefined method `order' for #<String:0xb6157cbc>

Comment: may i know please. why you are doing search2+search1

Comment: Reason is because I need to add the results of the 2 scopes and perform a search

Comment: please try to print value of search1 and search2 separately

Comment: I could do that but there are issues like pagination and sorting which I need to consider

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@search =  @search2.concat(@search1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately am still getting: can't convert Searchlogic::Search into Array